# How to use both LessCSS compiler and CSSO in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

I am using PhpStorm. I'm having problem with 2 file watchers.

`.min` files does not get updated on save in `.less` file.

I need first to compile Less to CSS and then to minify that same file.

Comment: 1) *".min files does not get updated on save in .less file"* Use `Output paths to refresh` for that -- the IDE will check that file looking for changes after current  File Watcher finished running.

Comment: 2) *"I need first to compile Less to CSS and then to minify that same file."* Use 2 file watchers: second one has to run after the first one (so it needs to be located after/below the first one).

Comment: I tried to switch both file watchers and it does not work.

Comment: I don't know what to put in 'Output paths to refresh'

Comment: Show what you have there right now. Maybe I can help (I'm not using Less or CSSO myself though .. so cannot test it locally).

Comment: https://prnt.sc/1lv2jv2
https://prnt.sc/1lv2n3d
https://prnt.sc/1lv2q0j

Comment: `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css` shoudl work.  I'm using `node-sass` and it's `$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css:$FileNameWithoutExtension$.css.map` (because it's 2 files that are generated).

Comment: A few thoughts: 1) Show what you have for the `Working Dir`. I assume it will be `$FileDir$` 2) Generated files are placed next to the source file(s). So if source is `C:\Project\assets\main.css` then generated file will be `C:\Project\assets\main.min.css` 3) Disable "Auto-save edited files..." option -- so it gets triggered only on manual Save and not automatically after 0.5 sec delay. 4) I assume that the actual command is executed correctly (no errors etc)? 5) Try restarting your computer -- it helps in many situations; maybe it;'s one of them).

Comment: I do not have a project right where I was using such "chained" thingy (plus, it was like 4-5 years ago I've last time used it) ... but it definitely worked for me back then. Just in case: official help page, may give some ideas: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-file-watchers.html

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-43186 -- this ticket asks for being able to run multiple File Wtachers "synchronously" / as a pipeline because sometimes they are racing for the same file. Or this one (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-17680) where it about different issue that arises after using chained file watchers. So it definitely works (worked in the past at very least0

Answer (score 0):

> .min files does not get updated on save in .less file

Use `Output paths to refresh` for that -- the IDE will check such path(s) looking for changes after current File Watcher finished running.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/using-file-watchers.html#transpilerBehaviour

> I need first to compile Less to CSS and then to minify that same file.

Use 2 file watchers: second one will run after the first one (so it needs to be located after/below the first one).

So I have:

- First watcher will take `main.scss` and compile into `main.css` (using **node-sass**) and placed next to the source file.
- Second will run after that on `main.css` and will make `main.min.css` using CSSO CSS Optimizer.

**The File Watchers:**

[image]
*(please ignore disabled ones: this is quite old test project; it keeps all the stuff from the past experiments)*

**SCSS Watcher (using node-sass):**

[image]

**CSSO CSS Optimizer watcher:**

[image]

Please note that I'm using custom scope: this is to limit these watchers to those specific folders only (it's test project after all; it has tons of experiments).

**Here is the recording/proof** that it works just fine: all 3 files are opened and get refreshed automatically by IDE: I only hit the Save button that triggers File Watchers.

[image]

A folder structure just in case:

[image]